# Generating a list of all truth assignments given a list of variables in SML?

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to write a function in SML that given a list of variables, it returns a list of tuples of every possible boolean assignment.

Essentially, I want the code to do this:

```
fun allAssignments ["p", "q"] = 
  [[("p", True),  ("q", True) ]
   [("p", True),  ("q", False)]
   [("p", False), ("q", True) ]
   [("p", False), ("q", False)]]
```

However, I wrote this function and although it makes sense to me, I keep getting tycon mismatch errors and I can't rectify it:

```
fun allAssignments nil = [[]]
  | allAssignments (x::xs) = [(x, true)::allAssignments xs] @ [(x, false)::allAssignments xs]
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your example, `allAssignments` needs to have the type `string list -> (string * bool) list list` (or potentially `'a list -> ('a * bool) list list` or `''a list -> (''a * bool) list list`, but I'll just stick with `string` for simplicity; the implementation is the same either way).

So, `allAssignments xs` must have the type `(string * bool) list list`, and `(x, true)` must have the type `string * bool`. But then `(x, true) :: allAssignments xs` is a type mismatch, because `::` expects its second argument to be a list whose elements have the same type as its first argument, whereas in your case the second argument is a list whose elements are *lists* (which the first argument is not).

If we imagine a version of Standard ML that didn't actually check types, your version of `allAssignments` would give the following results:

- `allAssignments []` → `[[]]`
- `allAssignments ["q"]` → `[[("q", true), []], [("q", false), []]]`
- `allAssignments ["p", "q"]` → `[[("p", true), [("q", true), []], [("q", false), []]], [("p", false), [("q", true), []], [("q", false), []]]]`

As you can see, it doesn't really work out. One problem is that the assignments of `"q"` are nested in more levels of lists than the assignments of `"p"` (hence the type error). Another problem is that `("p", true)` and `("p", false)` each appear only once, whereas `("q", true)` and `("q", false)` each appear twice.

To fix this, you need to actually "open up" `allAssignments xs` and prepend `(x, true)` to each of the individual lists that it contains, and then the same for `(x, false)`.

Here's one way, using `map`:

```
fun allAssignments nil = [nil]
 |  allAssignments (x::xs) =
      (map (fn assignments => (x, true) :: assignments) (allAssignments xs))
      @ (map (fn assignments => (x, false) :: assignments) (allAssignments xs))
```

though I should mention that this implementation is not at all optimal; both the computation time and the memory usage can be reduced significantly, especially if you don't care about the order in which the assignments are returned.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense! Thanks so much for the assistance!

Comment: @NessEarthbound: My pleasure!